# wordpress Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I have set php memory limit from whm to 256M from WHM > PHP Configuration Editor.
Even so, my wordpress website and admin is showing me an error like below.

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 36175872) (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/XXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 14272
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 35127296) (tried to allocate 1966080 bytes) in /home/XXXX/public_html/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 5427
```

I also tried to add following line to the top of wp-config.php, but no luck and same error.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

can anyone suggest me or tell me what may be the solution?

Comment: Why is Wordpress using so much memory? Normally, 32M should be more than enough...

Comment: I am not sure may be it's some plugins, since I have separated more memory what may be the issue or how to solve it?

Comment: The errors occur in ``class-simplepie.php``, which seems to belong to "simplepie", used to create RSS feeds. The second line says ``tried to allocate 1966080 bytes`` , which is about 1.8MB, quite a lot for a single statement IMHO! I am not familiar with wordpress or the simpliepie plugin, but IMHO tracking down the error would be a better solution than just increasing the memory limit. Either look at the code or try getting help at from the simplepie people.

Answer (score 7):

I finally think I've solved the White Screen of Death from PHP out of memory Fatal Errors.

Full details here: http://www.isthisyourhomework.com/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/

If setting the WordPress and PHP memory limits doesn't work for you, try adding/edditing the following line in either your Apache conf files. I didn't have access to those, so I added the following line to the `.htaccess` file in my WP server's document root:

```
RLimitMEM max
```

Many hosts have set limits on each user on shared-use servers. The above setting will unfetter your server and banish the WSOD.

Comment: Copy the relevant parts from the article into your answer.  Link-only answers are no good when the link breaks....

Answer (score 2):

The [SimplePie people reckon](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/i_m_getting_memory_leaks) that this is caused by a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33595).  It was fixed in PHP version 5.3.  Upgrading might help.

Newer versions of SimplePie use less memory but still suffer from the same PHP bug that causes lots of cached items to cause you to use loads of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the memory limit in php.ini(or through WHM service configuration page)? If so, try rebooting Apache

Comment: yes I changed the value server wide and restarted the apache. furthermore when I check the php configuration values from phpinfo() it does shows the memory limit of 256M, but somehow wordpress is not utilizing it. what should I do?