# Out of memory error despite raised limits

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the WP eCommerce plugin on my WordPress site. I have added 3500 products manually. But after that, I have added 10,000 more products in the database. Therefore I'm uploading it with a SQL query. But when added, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 366215168) (tried to allocate 82 bytes) in /.../wp-includes/meta.php on line 571
```

I have set the memory limit, but still the problem persists.

Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you restarted server?

Comment: how many memory limit in php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to change it.

1. Wordpress file **wp-config.php**

   `define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’64M’);`
2. **Php.ini** line `memory_limit = 64M`
3. **Htaccess** `php_value memory_limit 64M`
4. Php.ini in php code

   `ini_set("memory_limit","64M");`

You can always check what are current settings of php.ini with code below.

```
echo ini_get("memory_limit");
```

**Edited**

[You may find your answer here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887794/wordpress-fatal-error-out-of-memory)

Comment: Thanks,I have try this also, i changed the memory limit from wp-config.php but it did not resolved my problem.